# GWT open.window on top window

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT in my projects, when I use the open.window the window opens in the back not in the front.  I can find nothing to fix this.  I've tried something called the z-index, but there is next to no documentation about this.  And it didn't work.

Comment: z-index is not related to windows - it is used to manage content within a single window, unless by "window" you mean something else, like a popup  panel.

Comment: What code do you use to open a new window?

Comment: asksomething.setCommand(new Command() {
   @Override
   public void execute() {
    Window.open("http://www.google.com/somethinghere.aspx", "_top", "");


   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Set focus on a new window. Probably via some kind of JSNI method which will contain something like this `$wnd.focus()`.